# How to check object reference is type of base class or derived in assignment operator overload

Tags: c++, assignment-operator, dynamic-cast

I have two classes: Base and Derived. I want to dynamic_cast base class reference into Derived class reference as follows:

```
class Base
{
    ~Base() {}
};

class Derived: public Base
{
    public:
        Derived& operator=(const Base& aObj)
        {
            Base::operator=(aObj);
            try
            {
                const Derived& d = dynamic_cast<const Derived&> (aObj);
            }
            catch (std::bad_cast exp)
            {
                cout << "exception";
            }
        }
};
```

Above code compiled successfully. But on running it, gave segmentation fault on following line:

```
const Derived& d = dynamic_cast<const Derived&> (aObj);
```

What am I doing wrong? My purpose of doing this to copy all value if aObj is type of derived class and assigning default values to extra member variables of derived class, if aObj is type of Base class.

Comment: It would be more appropriate to use `if (auto d = dynamic_cast<const Derived*>(&aObj)) { ... }`. This avoids the exception being thrown in the first place.

Comment: @chris i used this too. and seg fault is coming. stack trace showing following :
__cxxabiv1::__dynamic_cast (src_ptr=0xdf93c8, src_type=0x88ceb0 <typeinfo for Base>, dst_type=0x88ce98 <typeinfo for Derived>, src2dst=0)

Comment: It shouldn't make a difference to behaviour, it's just more appropriate to avoid throwing and immediately catching an exception that's easy to avoid throwing in the first place. Anyway, it's not normal for this to segfault.

Comment: Can you provide an [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) ?

Comment: What calling code causes the segfault?

Comment: What does `Base::operator=(aObj);` do?

Comment: @FabioTurati it call base class assignment operator

Comment: You are right, it works. What confused me is that you are discarding the returned value, so I thought it wouldn't do anything in practice, but I realize I was wrong. False alarm, sorry!

Comment: You your life be easier if you composed (i.e. contained a base) instead of inheriting? Then the defaults will (probably) do the right thing

Comment: Does `Base` have any virtual functions?

Comment: You shouldn't need to know. Design smell here.

Comment: `dynamic_cast` should fail to compile here, since `Base` has no virtual function